# Parsing a multi-range request response swift

Tags: swift, http, range, nsurlsession

```
HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Content-Type: multipart/byteranges; boundary=3d6b6a416f9b5
Content-Length: 282

--3d6b6a416f9b5
Content-Type: video/mp4
Content-Range: bytes 0-50/1270

DATA............

--3d6b6a416f9b5
Content-Type: video/mp4
Content-Range: bytes 100-150/1270

eta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; c
--3d6b6a416f9b5--
```

This is the example response I got from Mozilla. I am using swift and creating a multi-part range request using URLSession. I get a response that I convert to `[UInt8]` and also `String` with ascii encoding I can get the boundary string. But I am wondering how I can extract just the content inside each range request, reliably regardless of content-type and content-range. I realise I can get the `--3d6b6a416f9b5 .... --3d6b6a416f9b5` blocks but how to exactly remove the content header.

```
let ranges : [(Int, Int)] = [...]
var range_request = "bytes="
for r in ranges {
    range_request += "\(r.0)-\(r.1), "
}
range_request = String(range_request.dropLast(2))
var streamRequest = URLRequest(url: streamURL)
streamRequest.setValue(range_request, forHTTPHeaderField: "Range")
let sessionConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default
sessionConfig.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 1
let session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfig)
let task = session.downloadTask(with: streamRequest) { (tempLocalURL, response, url_error) in
    if url_error != nil {
        //handle error
    } else {
        do {
            //assume successful 206 response for now...
            let httpResponse = response as! HTTPURLResponse 
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: tempLocalURL!)
            let boundaryPhrase = (httpResponse.allHeaderFields["Content-Type"]! as! String).replacingOccurrences(of: "multipart/byteranges; boundary=", with: "")
            let totalData = [UInt8](data)
            let stringTotalData = (String(data: data, encoding: .ascii)!

        } catch {
            //handle error
        }
    }
}
task.resume()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let data = try Data(contentsOf: tempLocalURL!)
let content_type = httpResponse.allHeaderFields["Content-Type"]! as! String
let boundary_word = content_type.replacingOccurrences(of: "multipart/byteranges; boundary=", with: "")
let boundary_phrase = "--\(boundary_word)"
let input_data = [UInt8](data)
var bodies : [[UInt8]] = []
var current_body = 0
if boundary_word != "video/mp4" {
    let boundary_phrase_ints = [UInt8](boundary_phrase.utf8)
    let header_end_ints = [UInt8]("\r\n\r\n".utf8)
    var i = 0
    var potential_body : [UInt8] = []
    while i < (input_data.count - boundary_phrase_ints.count) {
        if potential_body == boundary_phrase_ints {
            let potential_end_header = Array(input_data[i..<(i + header_end_ints.count)])
            if potential_end_header == header_end_ints {
                let start = i + header_end_ints.count
                let upper_limit = start + ranges[current_body].1 - ranges[current_body].0
                bodies.append(Array(input_data[start...upper_limit]))
                current_body += 1
                i = upper_limit
            }
        } else {
            potential_body = Array(input_data[i..<(i + boundary_phrase_ints.count)])
            if potential_body == boundary_phrase_ints {
                i += boundary_phrase_ints.count
            }
        }
        i += 1
    }
    //in my case I don't need to split the data into separate ranges.
} else {
    //handle single range case
}
```

So I was able to solve the problem. Here is my code. In my case I need to to deal with the data as [UInt8] as it was a video I was requesting, that is why I had to convert the boundary phrase into [UInt8] as well as the header end.

So by using the boundary phrase you can extract each body - if you did it with a string you could just do components and remove the first and last elements since these are bogus. Next inside each body you can find the end of the header by look for "\r\n\r\n" which seems to be unique.